# choosing between class level or method level generics

Tags: java, generics

How to choose between class level or method level definitions of generic types? Below I have 2 examples with alternative (correct) implementations for some problem. I'm trying to understand the differences, and why I would choose one over the other.

**Example 1:**
Given some algorithm which processes a search tree. To aid the user in debugging, certain states in the algorithm fire an event. The user can implement an `EventListener` which listens to these events, e.g. some logger utility.

```
public Node<N extends Number>{ .. }
```

An event can be implemented in the following 2 ways:

*Option 1: (class level)*

```
public class PruneNodeEvent<N extends Number> extends EventObject
{
    public final Node<N> node; //Node being pruned

    public PruneNodeEvent(Object source, Node<N> node)
    {
        super(source);
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

*Option 2: (method level)*

```
public class PruneNodeEvent extends EventObject
{
    public final Node<? extends Number> node; //Node being pruned

    public PruneNodeEvent(Object source, Node<? extends Number> node)
    {
        super(source);
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

Which considerations should be made to choose one over the other?

**Example 2:**
Given some abstract implementation of an algorithm which listens to Decisions. Each time a new Decision is made, the algorithm updates its data structures, but it doesn't store the decision. Since this is an abstract class (template), we don't know how the end user is going to use this class. Again we have 2 choices:

*Option 1: (class level)*

```
public abstract class AbstractAlgorithm<T extends Data>
implements DecisionListener<T> {

    @Override
    public void makeDecision(Decision<T> d)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void reverseDecision(Decision<T> d)
    {
    }
}
```

*Option 2: (method level)*

```
public abstract class AbstractAlgorithm implements DecisionListener
{
    @Override
    public void makeDecision(Decision<? extends Data> d) {
    }

    @Override
    public void reverseDecision(Decision<? extends Data> d) {
    }
}
```

Which considerations should be made to choose one over the other?

Including good references dealing with Dos, Don'ts and considerations in designing generic classes (ala Effective Java 2nd Edition) to support your answer is encouraged.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: These examples both cover consumers, consider the case of a supplier (for instance `List.get(...)`, what if that returned `? extends Object`).

Comment: @RomanC the first reply is already a nice, **factual** answer... Not all design questions are based on the preference of the author, or the alignment of the stars...

Comment: @AndyTurner Huh? I didn't get what are you asking my opinion or your opinion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Example 1

The main difference between these two is in what you can do with `node`.

Let's just add in a third option for completeness:

```
public final Node<? super Number> node;
```

Remember the acronym **PECS**:

> Producer Extends, Consumer Super

- In the second option, `Node<? extends T> node` is a *producer*: you can only invoke methods which produce a `T` on it.

  ```
  T instanceOfT = node.get();
  ```

  but you can't invoke a consumer method with a parameter other than `null`:

  ```
  node.accept(null);         // OK.
  node.accept(instanceOfT);  // Compiler error.
  ```
- In the third option, `Node<? super T> node` is a *consumer*: you can only invoke methods on it which *take* a `T`, e.g.

  ```
  node.accept(instanceOfT);
  ```

  but you can't invoke a producer method and assign its result to a type dependent on `T`:

  ```
  Object obj = node.get();         // OK.
  List<?> list = node.getList();   // OK.
  T t = node.get();                // Compiler error.
  List<T> listT = node.getList();  // Compiler error.
  ```
- In the first option, `Node<T> node` is *both* a producer and a consumer, since it is the intersection of options 2 and 3 (the type which is both `<? extends T>` and `<? super T>` is `<T>`):

  ```
  T t = node.get();  // OK.
  node.accept(t);    // OK.
  ```

So, the choice between the 3 options depends upon what you need to do with `node`:

- If you need it to produce `T`s, choose either `<T>` or `<? extends T>`;
- If you need it to consume `T`s, choose either `<T>` or `<? super T>`;
- If you need it to produce *and* consume `T`s, choose `<T>`.

> Example 2

Use the first one if you only want to invoke the method for specific parameter types of `Decision`, e.g.

```
AbstractAlgorithm<StringData> foo = new AbstractAlgorithm<>();
foo.makeDecision(new Decision<StringData>());   // OK.
foo.makeDecision(new Decision<IntegerData>());  // Compiler error.
```

Use the second if you want to be able to invoke the method for any type with the same `AbstractAlgorithm`, e.g.

```
AbstractAlgorithm foo = new AbstractAlgorithm();
foo.makeDecision(new Decision<StringData>());   // OK.
foo.makeDecision(new Decision<IntegerData>());  // OK.
```

Comment: hm, and what about the first example?

Comment: @JorisKinable added.